# Need to extract values through array names in tcl array which has lot of indices

Tags: arrays, regex, tcl

I have an array that looks like this:

```
params(ddns_a_servers,sfg)     = sfg
params(ddns_a_zone)            = dsgfs
params(dhcp_option_encoding,1) = string
params(dhcp_option_id,1)       = 1
params(dhcp_option_value,1)    = fdsg
params(ddns_bsr_servers,dasf   = dasf
params(log)                    = 1
params(svc_dnsservers)         = 1.1.1.1
params(svc_domainname)         = rr
```

I need to extract the values for the indices `ddns_*_servers`. I used glob style matching and regexp matching with the array names command

```
foreach srv [array names params -regexp ddns_.+_servers,.+]


foreach srv [array names params "ddns_*_servers,*"]
```

On printing out $srv I get :
`'ddns_a_servers,sfg'` instead of just `'sfg'`

I am getting the index and the value along with it. Not able to understand why this is. I have used this a few times before and it has worked perfectly. Where I am going wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using [array **names**] -- you still need to get the value out of the array given the name you have.

```
array set params {
    ddns_a_servers,sfg      sfg
    ddns_a_zone             dsgfs
    dhcp_option_encoding,1  string
    dhcp_option_id,1        1
    dhcp_option_value,1     fdsg
    ddns_bsr_servers,dasf   dasf
    log                     1
    svc_dnsservers          1.1.1.1
    svc_domainname          rr
}

foreach name [array names params "ddns_*_servers,*"] {
    puts [format "%s => %s" $name $params($name)]
}
```

```
ddns_bsr_servers,dasf => dasf
ddns_a_servers,sfg => sfg
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! Thank you. I just forgot about that and was expecting the value to come out of it.